# Pytest does not run the code from my package module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am following the book "Learn Python The Hard Way" and in exercise 46 we make a skeleton structure for projects and install Pytest to test the project code. All cool and dandy until I try to run the test for my package. The test marks as successful but nothing from my module code shows up, and only when I test individually the module with a `test_Dandy2.py` file does the code run.
This is how my directory is organized (based on the book exercise):

```
project_1\
  bin\
  docs\
  project1\
    __init__.py
    Dandy2.py
  tests\
    __init__.py
    test_project1.py
    test_Dandy2.py
  setup.py
```

I tried to write `import Dandy2` on my `__init__` file in my package directory and then I got an `ImportError`. I looked up all over stack overflow and most answers talk about my project file being out of the python PATH. However, my test marks as successful, and when running the test for the module individually it runs the code normally.
I don't know if this is how it should work, as the book gives no explanation whatsoever and the LPTHW forum is very dead. Maybe it is because I am using a windows os, and running the pytest in Powershell and have something to twist in order to make it work (like I had to do to run scripts, where I needed to change the execution policy of my system).

PS: Here is what shows up in powershell. Maybe there is something wrong in my code or the test is behaving as it should and I simply didn't understand how pytest works. When I only run `test_project1.py` I only get the test results and not the code in my module.

```
    (lpthw) PS C:\Users\desou\OneDrive\Desktop\venvs\projects\project_1> python -m pytest -s
    ============================================== test session starts ===============================================
    
    platform win32 -- Python 3.12.2, pytest-8.0.2, pluggy-1.4.0
    rootdir: C:\Users\desou\OneDrive\Desktop\venvs\projects\project_1
    
    collecting ... Hello this is a test program.
    
    You will be tested, how much is 77 + 33?
    
    \> 4
    
    Test complete. You've proved that you lack math skills.
    
    collected 2 items
    
    tests\test_Dandy2.py SETUP!
    I RAN!
    .TEAR DOWN!
    
    tests\test_project1.py SETUP!
    I RAN!
    .TEAR DOWN!
    
    
    =============================================== 2 passed in 2.22s ================================================
```

this is my module code:
print("Hello this is a test program.")
print("You will be tested, how much is 77 + 33?")

```
x = input("> ")

if x != '110':
   print("Test complete. You've proved that you lack math skills.")
   pass

else:
   print("Test complete. Congratulations, you have a brain.")
   pass
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you running `pytest`?

From your description, you may need to add the `tests` directory. E.g. Assuming you're in the `project_1` directory, run;

```
pytest tests
```

Comment: I am running pytest with the -s flag, otherwise powershell rises an OSError. When I run the test the way you say, it runs both "test_project1.py" and "test_Dandy2.py". As always I get the successful test message, but only the file that test exclusively the module runs the code. My file that test the package itself run no code.

Comment: Ah! `pytest` is intended to search for and run tests that check the main app, rather than run the app itself. Unless you have tests that will run the package, it won't run your main code.  Have a look at the [conventions-for-python-test-discovery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery) documentation to see how `pytest` finds tests to run.

Answer (score 0):

Run the tests from the project root directory "project_1".
It is better to understand how Python searches for modules and packages.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots

Comment: I am running the tests from this directory, since in the book it says to run the tests in the same directory of setup.py and above the tests directory. Still I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Removed my previous answer based on the first comment to this answer.

Here is the updated reply:

Got it! Then the answer is that running with pytest, the above behaviour is expected .

pytest collects any methods starting with "test" prefix as tests to run from current working directory & its subdirectories. while collecting tests if it founds any executable code from module import , it will run during collection of tests even before running the setup method. That is why the module code ran during the collection of tests process as being displayed in your output above.

Then after collecting tests process completes, pytest starts running those tests in an order of collection. While executing each test from the collection, it ensures to run setup methods before running each test, and it runs the test method and agains ensures to run teardown() methods after each test completes.

Hope, this has clarified your query.

[Open this official doc link on pytest for more details](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/contents.html)

Comment: yeah, but since nosetests got abandoned I changed for pytest. I used pynose but still got the same problem.

Comment: Got it! Then the answer is that running with pytest, the above behaviour is expected .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. The output I was receiving from my tests is expected, as pytest will search and run the package, but won't output any code. It will display an output if you make tests to run the package and give an output. I guess it was my inexperience showing in full display.